# Calling oracle procedure without putting all parameters

Tags: oracle, plsql

I'm using oracle procedure which looks like this

```
CREATE PROCEDURE spName (
    pCurosr OUT refcursor,
    par2 IN VARCHAR := NULL,
        ....
        ....
    par98 IN VARCHAR := NULL,
    error OUT NUMBER
) AS
BEGIN
    ....
    ....
END
```

Problem is, some procedures take too many parameters which have been set NULL as default value.
What I want to know is, whether it is possible to exec procedure like this?

```
exec spName(:refcur, :par5 = 'value', :error);
```

Only supply parameters that I want and all other parameters are set as default values.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

For example, with a procedure like this

```
create or replace procedure testProc ( pOut OUT number,
                                       pIn1 IN  number := null,
                                       pIn2 IN  number := null,
                                       pIn3 IN  number := null,
                                       pIn4 IN  number := null
                                     ) is ...
```

You can use named parameter assignment:

```
declare
    vOut number;
begin
    testProc (pOut => vOut,
              pIn3 => 3
             );             
end;
```

The unnamed parameters will take the default value.

The order of named parameters is not important here, so you can do, for example,

```
testProc (pIn1 => 1,
          pOut => vOut,
          pIn3 => 3
         );
```